# Calculate the Euler characteristic to $\langle a,b,c \mid abacb^{-1}c^{-1}\rangle$ and determine what standard surface it is homeomorphic to

Tags: general-topology

Calculate the Euler characteristic to $\langle a,b,c \mid abacb^{-1}c^{-1}\rangle$ and determine what standard surface it is homeomorphic to.

I first tried to draw it, which obviously didnt work, and dont really know how to get forward without having some sense of how it looks.

Comment: How is this even a *surface*?

Comment: It has odd Euler characteristics. It isn't orientable, so it'd be quite hard to draw it.

Comment: @SimoneRamello that was what I felt when I tried but its a problem from Lee's book "Introduction to Topological Manifold" so I suppose it works. My teacher sent a tip: "draw and chase through the identifications. There is a unique 0-cell, 3 1-cell and one 2-cell. And I mean if you assume there are three sides (a triangle) then I suppose it makes sense. But still think its a good exercise to draw it... or at least try

Comment: But doesnt I need to draw it to see that? @SimoneRamello

Comment: I was taught how to find Euler characteristics of surfaces from their polygonal representation **before** learning about chain complexes (I still haven't studied them now, tbh), so my method is as follows: you count how many equivalence classes of vertices there are, where two vertices are equivalent iff they will be identified; you then calculate #equiv. classes - #letters + 1, and this gives you the Euler characteristic. I might not understand what you mean by "draw", tho.

Comment: @SimoneRamello ok thanks! But what do you mean with identified in "... iff they will be identified"?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the relation is equivalent to $abacb^{-1}c^{-1}b^{-1}b$, and thus $(baba)(cb^{-1}c^{-1}b^{-1})$. This gives a connect sum of $\Bbb RP^2$ and the Klein bottle $K$. Indeed, the cellular chain complex has one $0$-cell, three $1$-cells, and one $2$-cell. The $2$-cell has attaching map $1\mapsto 2a$, so $H_2(X)=0$ and $H_1(X)=\Bbb Z/2\oplus \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z$. In particular the Euler characteristic is odd (which you can see from the chain complex anyway), so in fact the surface *must* be $\Bbb R P^2\# K\cong \Bbb RP^2\times \Bbb R P^2\times\Bbb R P^2$.

Comment: I guess that wasn't really a hint